# Java Web + Ajax + Servlets

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, json

**Estou com muita dificuldade ao tentar receber o data no Ajax.**

Quando executo o código, recebo o status 200 e em network no depurador do Chrome consigo ver o retorno, mas não consigo fazer mais nada com o data, como por exemplo dar um alert(data) ou qualquer outra coisa útil.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

**JS - Ajax**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#calcular').on('click', function () {

            var nome = $('#nome').val();
            var peso = $('#peso').val();
            var altura = $('#altura').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'calcular',
                    method: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        nome: nome,
                        peso: peso,
                        altura: altura
                    },
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        400: function() {
                            alert("Chamada inválida!");
                        }
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
```

**Servlet**

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {

        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
        double peso = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("peso"));
        double altura = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("altura"));

        IMC imc = new IMC(nome, peso, altura);
        String user = imc.getNome();
        double resultado = imc.getIMC();

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.printf(Locale.US, "{ \"user\": %s, \"resultado\": %.2f }", user, resultado);

    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

}

**Classe IMC**

```
package models;

public class IMC {

private String nome;
private double peso, altura;

public IMC (String nome, double peso, double altura){
    this.nome = nome;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.altura = altura;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public double getIMC () {
    return peso / (altura * altura);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O meu erro era a falta de aspas no valor do Json.